# PHP JSON Arrays within an Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a script that loops through and retrieves some specified values and adds them to a php array. I then have it return the value to this script:

```
//Returns the php array to loop through
$test_list= $db->DatabaseRequest($testing);

//Loops through the $test_list array and retrieves a row for each value
foreach ($test_list as $id => $test) {

                $getList = $db->getTest($test['id']);

                $id_export[] = $getList ;

            }

print(json_encode($id_export));
```

This returns a JSON value of:

```
[[{"id":1,"amount":2,"type":"0"}], [{"id":2,"amount":25,"type":"0"}]]
```

This is causing problems when I try to parse the data onto my android App. The result needs to be something like this:

```
[{"id":1,"amount":2,"type":"0"}, {"id":2,"amount":25,"type":"0"}]
```

I realize that the loop is adding the array into another array. My question is how can I loop through a php array and put or keep all of those values into an array and output them in the JSON format above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

of course I think $getList contains an array you database's columns,

use

```
$id_export[] = $getList[0]
```

Maybe can do some checks to verify if your $getList array is effectively 1 size

Answer (score 1):

`$db->getTest()` seems to be returning an array of a single object, maybe more,  which you are then adding to a new array.  Try one of the following:

If there will only ever be one row, just get the `0` index (the simplest):

```
            $id_export[] = $db->getTest($test['id'])[0];
```

Or get the current array item:

```
            $getList = $db->getTest($test['id']);

            $id_export[] = current($getList); //optionally reset()
```

If there may be more than one row, merge them (probably a better and safer idea regardless):

```
            $getList = $db->getTest($test['id']);

            $id_export = array_merge((array)$id_export, $getList);
```